# Can't get rid of dead ends while finding all possible routes in a graph

Tags: c, graph

So I had a homework about finding all routes between two nodes specified by the user in a graph. The code works but there is a small problem.

[image]

So I tell the program to tell me all possible routes between nodes 0 and 3. And this is the output (not exact output):

0-3

0-1-2-3

0-2-1-3

So the problem is with the last route. Instead of going 0-2-3 it goes 0-2-1-3. Because it doesn't know 1 is a dead end. So either I should not do anything for a dead end node, or dont print them when i understand they are dead ends.

I tried doing some recursion stuff to check if the next node is a dead end, but they turned out to be infinite loops.

So how can I fix this problem?

```
/*
   Description: Finds all possible routes from a starting node to an end node
    that is picked by the user.

   NOTE: This code is working in devc++ but it has problems in visual studio
    because of different functions.

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

find_routes2(int start, int finish, char route[9], char route_temp[9],
             int mark[4], int graph[4][4])
{
    int i;
    char route_temp2[9];

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (graph[start][i] != 0 && mark[i] != 0) {
            sprintf(route_temp2, "-> %d", i);
            strcat(route, route_temp2);
            if (i == finish) {
                printf("\nRoute: %s\n", route);
                strcpy(route, route_temp);
            } else {
                mark[start] = 0;
                find_routes2(i, finish, route, route_temp, mark, graph);
            }
        }
    }
}

find_routes(int start, int finish, char route[9], char route_temp[9],
            int mark[4], int graph[4][4])
{
    int i;
    char route_temp2[9];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (graph[start][i] != 0 && mark[i] != 0) {
            sprintf(route_temp2, "-> %d ", i);
            strcat(route, route_temp2);

            if (i == finish) {
                printf("\nRoute: %s\n\n", route);
            } else {
                mark[start] = 0;
                find_routes2(i, finish, route, route_temp, mark, graph);
            }
            memset(mark, 1, 4*sizeof(int));
            strcpy(route, route_temp);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int graph[4][4] = { { 0, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                        { 1, 1, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, 1, 0 } };
    int mark[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    char route[9];
    char route_temp[9];
    int i, j;

    printf("NOTE: This code is working in devc++ but it has problems \n"
           "in visual studio because of different functions\n\n");
    printf("This is the graph(nodes are 0, 1, 2 ,3):\n\n0-1-2-3\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", graph[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("Select a starting node from \"0, 1, 2 ,3\": ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    sprintf(route, "-> %d", i);

    strcpy(route_temp, route);

    printf("\nSelect a different ending node from \"0, 1, 2 ,3\""
           "(if you dont get any results it\n"
           "means either you entered wrong numbers or there are no routes): ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    if (i == j || i > 3 || j >3 || i < 0 || j < 0) {
        printf("\nStart and finish nodes are same or wrong number(s) have"
               " been entered. Please try \nagain.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    find_routes(i, j, route, route_temp, mark, graph);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `route` is too small for 4 steps with the format `"-> %d"`.  Make it at least 14 bytes.

Comment: Omitted return type is an obsolete syntax.  Make `find_routes` and `find_routes2` `void`.

Comment: You should use pointers instead of arrays, this will allow you to deal with bigger mesh

Comment: Your lines are way too long.  Break them to prevent horizontal scroll, it makes your code hard to read.

Comment: @chqrlie I even calculated the length of that string i dont know why i made it 9. Thanks but for some reason program works same no matter its 9 or 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void display_route (int route[4], int n)
{
    ...
}

void find_routes_helper (const int graph[4][4], int finish,
                         int route[4], int n, bool mark[4])
{
    // I is the last vertex of ROUTE
    int i = route[n - 1];

    // if ROUTE ends at FINISH, the search is over
    if (i == finish) {
        display_route (route, n);
        return;
    }

    // for each vertex J adjacent to I that is not already in ROUTE
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (!mark[j] && graph[i][j]) {
            // add J to ROUTE
            route[n] = j;
            n++;
            mark[j] = true;
            // search routes that begin with ROUTE
            find_routes_helper (graph, finish, route, n, mark);
            // backtrack : remove J from ROUTE
            n--;
            mark[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

void find_routes (const int graph[4][4], int start, int finish)
{
    // set things up so that ROUTE consists exactly of START

    int route[4];
    int n;
    bool mark[4];


    route[0] = start;
    n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        mark[i] = false;
    }
    mark[start] = true;

    find_routes_helper (graph, finish, route, n, mark);
}
```

Note how the search code represents a route as an array of nodes and how the display logic is completely separate. Note also how the helper data structures are declared in find_routes() and hidden from main().

Comment: When i first tried writing this program i tried doing it with one function :P . I should seperate my functions more. Thanks dude i looked at the code, i will try to understand it fully.

Answer (score 0):

You print the discovered route at the top of your recursive stack, in function `find_routes()`, but if you do it that way then you can print only one route per iteration of the loop in that function -- that is, only one route with each choice of initial edge.  There can be more than one such, such as two routes from node 1 to node 0 that both start with 0 -> 2.

Moreover, you provide no mechanism for function `find_routes2()` to indicate to its caller that it failed, so you will print exactly one route for each possible choice of initial leg.

The latter is actually the less serious problem; it will be rendered moot by fixing the first.  To do that, print the full discovered route each time you reach the destination vertex, instead of only after you return all the way to the top of the recursion.

Note also that you need to be careful with your vertex marking.  You take care to mark your nodes when you visit them, but you fail to *un*mark them when you finish that visit and are ready to try an alternative route from whatever node you are currently at.  This will prevent you from discovering all possible routes between some pairs of vertices in some graphs, including the one built in to your program.

Comment: Thats my problem. I couldnt came up with a way to tell he failed. But i didnt even realise the first thing you said because i was working with small graphs. I dont think there is something wrong with my vertex marking. When i reach finish i reset the markings. When i dont reach finish, i dont reset markings. Maybe you are right and i dont see it.

Comment: The test graph is not complex enough to really demonstrate the marking problem.  It would require there to be two distinct routes from start vertex to end vertex with the same first edge (given your present implementation), that diverge and then rejoin before reaching the end vertex.  That requires at least five vertices.  I guess you can take that as your marking being ok, but in my view only accidentally so.

Comment: I added comments to my code. What John talks about corresponds to the `mark[j] = 0;` line in `find_routes_helper()`. It is part of the backtracking part of the algorithm.